# Return list of custom class using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, return, user-defined-types

I have a class `Author.cs` as:

```
public class Author  
{  
   public Author()  
   { }  

   public int _AuthorID { get; set; }  
   public string _AuthorName { get; set; }  
   public List<Paper> _Papers { get; set; }  
}
```

and another class `Paper.cs` as:

```
public class Paper  
{  
   public Paper()  
   { }  

   public int _PaperID { get; set; }
   public List<int> _CoAuthors { get; set; }
   public int _VenueID { get; set; }
   public int _PaperCategory { get; set; }
   public int _Year { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a method in `Author.cs` class which returns authors for given Year and author between given Years.

I tried as following:

```
public List<Author> GetAuthorsByYear(List<Author> _fullList, int _year)
{
   return _fullList.Where(_author => _author.GetPaperYear() == _year).ToList();
}

public List<Author> GetAuthorsBetweenYears(List<Author> _fullList, int _startYear, int _endYear)
{
   return _fullList.Where(_author => _author.GetPaperYear() >= _startYear && _author.GetPaperYear() <= _endYear).ToList();
}
```

The method `GetPaperYear()` is not defined yet but it is intended to define such a method in class `Author.cs` to achieve the goal that's why shown here as dummy.

Similarly, I want to have methods like:

```
public List<int> GetCoAuthorsByYear(int _year)  
{
   // How to return list of coauthors by year
}  
public List<int> GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears(int _startYear, int _endYear)  
{
   // How to return list of coauthors between years
}  

public List<int> GetVenuesByYear(int _year)  
{
   // How to return list of venues by year
}  
public List<int> GetVenuesBetweenYears(int _startYear, int _endYear)  
{
   // How to return list of venues between years
}
```

How to achieve this using Linq?

Comment: That's already Linq, what more do you need?

Comment: I really don't get it, what is the problem with your approach?

Comment: Its Linq but as I also mentioned above, the method `GetPaperYear()` not defined yet in `Author.cs` class. `_Year` is a property of `Paper.cs` class, so if there is a method like this in `Author.cs` class, then Linq i.e. shown in the above code will be useful

Comment: If I correctly understood you could change `GetAuthorsByYear` method : `return _fullList.Where(_author => _author._Papers.Any(y => y._Year == _year)).ToList();` Sure, change the second year the same way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I hope so you get the problem now

Comment: You might want to lose the underscores, they're not helping.

Comment: @buffjape actually I'm habitual to use underscores, I want to let this habit go, I'm trying hard anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have separate method in the `Author` class like you asked in the question, it could look like:

```
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    { }

    public int _AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string _AuthorName { get; set; }
    public List<Paper> _Papers { get; set; }

    public bool HasPapersForYear(int year)
    {
        return _Papers.Any(_paper => _paper._Year == year);
    }

    public bool HasPapersForYears(int startYear, int endYear)
    {
        return _Papers.Any(_paper => _paper._Year >= startYear && _paper._Year <= endYear);
    }
}
```

And old methods are changed:

```
public List<Author> GetAuthorsByYear(List<Author> _fullList, int _year)
{
    return _fullList.Where(_author => _author.HasPapersForYear(_year)).ToList();
}

public List<Author> GetAuthorsBetweenYears(List<Author> _fullList, int _startYear, int _endYear)
{
    return _fullList.Where(_author => _author.HasPapersForYears(_startYear,_endYear)).ToList();
}
```

Also about the part of Venue and CoAuthors

```
    public List<int> GetCoAuthorsByYear(int _year)
    {
        var coAuthors = new List<int>();
        foreach(var paper in _Papers.Where(_paper => _paper._Year == _year))
        {
            coAuthors.AddRange(paper._CoAuthors);
        }
        return coAuthors;
    }
    public List<int> GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears(int _startYear, int _endYear)
    {
        var coAuthors = new List<int>();
        foreach(var paper in _Papers.Where(_paper => _paper._Year >= _startYear && _paper._Year <= _endYear))
        {
            coAuthors.AddRange(paper._CoAuthors);
        }
        return coAuthors;
    }

    public List<int> GetVenuesByYear(int _year)
    {
        var venues = new List<int>();
        foreach(var paper in _Papers.Where(_paper => _paper._Year == _year))
        {
            venues.Add(paper._VenueID);
        }
        return venues;
    }
    public List<int> GetVenuesBetweenYears(int _startYear, int _endYear)
    {
        var venues = new List<int>();
        foreach(var paper in _Papers.Where(_paper => _paper._Year >= _startYear && _paper._Year <= _endYear))
        {
            venues.Add(paper._VenueID);
        }
        return venues;
    }
```

This code could be refactored sure.

Comment: @Taufel I don't understand what you really mean (because of the lack of info) and how it is related to your initial question.

Comment: @Taufel why don't you just update the question with more details?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean, because `HasVenuesForYear` for me now it is the same as `HasPapersForYear`, because `Paper` class has Int32 value for `VenueID` and each paper has not null VenueId.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more details, please update your answer accordingly and also let me know whether are you updating your answer likewise?

Comment: @user2216--if we want to have a method like `GetPapersBetweenYears()` in class `Author.cs` then how do we write this method?

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq a bit deeper than you already used and change your return statement as:

In `GetAuthorsByYear()` method:

```
return _fullList.Where(_author => _author._Papers.Any(y => y._Year == _year)).ToList();
```

In `GetAuthorsBetweenYears()` method:

```
return _fullList.Where(_author => _author._Papers.Any(y => y._Year >= _startYear && y._Year <= _endYear))).ToList();
```

The method `GetPaperYear()` is no more required.

Comment: It is wrong solution. Look at the second method. If author has two papers - one for 2000 year, the second - 2020. If startYear is 2010, endYear is 2015, this author will be returned, but this is incorrect. He has at least one book that has year more than 2010 and at least one book that has year less than 2015.

Comment: I would like to get you seriously here, but unable to understand what you are pointing to?

Comment: At first - the second method even cannot be compiled.

Comment: But as your given example above, the author can't have paper beyond startYear and endYear, paper must lie between startYear and endYear and moreover its not an open ended or user choice to use whatever paper or whatever startYear or endYear values

Comment: Could you please read my first comment for this answer and look at `GetAuthorsBetweenYears()` method in it again. I gave an example when it is incorrect and the method shouldn't return author but it returns.

Comment: This method returns `author who has at least one paper in the year after min year and at least one paper in the year before max year' (it can be two different papers). But the method should return 'author who has at least one paper where year is between min year and max year'

Comment: How can you modify it correctly (the second method)?

Comment: `return _fullList.Where(_author => _author._Papers.Any(y => y._Year >= _startYear && y._Year <= _endYear))).ToList();`