# Count value at specific dictionary key C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, count, tuples

I have to count the value of a dictionary at specific key.  My code is:

```
foreach (CurrentCluster curCluster in curClusters){
   twObjClus.WriteLine("Cluster_ID: {0} - Cluster_Size: {1} \n",  
   curCluster.GetClusterID(), curCluster.GetClusterSize());
   twObjClus.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
    foreach (EvoObject eEvoObject in curCluster.GetClusterObjects()){
        Author eAuthor = (Author)eEvoObject.GetOriginalObject(); 

        twObjClus.WriteLine("\n");
        twObjClus.WriteLine(@"Author_ID: {0}, Author_Name: {1} ",  
        eAuthor.AuthorID, eAuthor.AuthorName);
        twObjClus.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");

        Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> tPapers =  
        eAuthor.GetPapersBetweenYears(year, year + 1);
        List<int> tCoAuthors =  
        eAuthor.GetCoAuthorsBetweenYears(year, year + 1);
        List<int> tVenues = eAuthor.GetVenuesBetweenYears(year, year + 1);
        foreach (var kvpaper in tPapers){
           // Key is Paper_ID, Item1 is Paper_Category, Item2 is Year
           twObjClus.WriteLine("PaperID: {0}, PaperCategory: {1}, Year: {2}",  
           kvpaper.Key, kvpaper.Value.Item1, kvpaper.Value.Item2);
        }
        foreach (var kvCoAuthor in tCoAuthors){
           twObjClus.WriteLine("CoAuthorID: {0}", kvCoAuthor);
        }
        foreach (var kvVenue in tVenues){
           twObjClus.WriteLine("VenueID: {0}", kvVenue);
        }
    } 
    twObjClus.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
twObjClus.Flush();    twObjClus.Close();
```

Now I want to count each different value at `Paper_Category` i.e. `Item1` of the `Tuple` in `Dictionary`.

**Minor Detail**
This is actually the clustering which I'm doing to get results from my data. As each cluster will have number of `Paper_Category`ies associated with some objects. What I want is to count each category and store that cluster as with single category i.e. the category with highest count.

If the `eAuthor` is a list and I have to check highest `Paper_Category` count among all `eAuthor`s, and each `eAuthor` may comprise several `Paper_Category`ies also, then how to count?

How can I count existence of each value of `Paper_Category` and write it as text?

Comment: Need more details, do you want to group by Paper_Category, please provide an example

Comment: Some minor details are there now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var categoryGroups = tPapers.Values.GroupBy(t => t.Item1);

foreach(var g in categoryGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Category:{0} Count:{1}", g.Key, g.Count());
```

> How can I select or store somewhere (i.e. in variable) the category with highest count?

```
var highestCount =  categoryGroups.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
     .Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
     .First();
Console.WriteLine("Category:{0} Count:{1}", highestCount.Category, highestCount.Count);
```

---

Since you want to get the paper-category-count across all authors in `eAuthor` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787860/return-list-of-custom-class-using-linq) seem to be your classes, use `SelectMany`:

```
var categoryGroups = eAuthor
    .SelectMany(a => a._Papers.Select(p => p._PaperCategory))
    .GroupBy(pc => pc);
// rest is same
```

Comment: How can I select or store somewhere (i.e. in variable) the category with highest count?

Comment: @taufel: i've provided one approach. If you need to store it outside of method scope or transfer it to a different method i would either use a class or a `Tuple<int,int>`(if it's not used outside of the class).

Comment: I'm going to provide some more code for better understanding, then you may cope the point to solve

Comment: @Taufel: i don't understand. What kind of list is `eAuthor`? Is this your model: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37787860/284240 and `eAuthor` is a `List<Author>`?

Comment: @Taufel: edited my answer again, use `SelectMany` to get all paper-categories

Comment: I've provided the code, please have a look at it, whereas I need the highest count for `Paper_Category` in each cluster

Comment: @Taufel: very confusing, you told that `eAuthor` is a list, now your code shows that it's a single `Author`. Isn't it simply `var categoryGroups = eAuthor._Papers.Select(p => p._PaperCategory)
    .GroupBy(pc => pc);`?

Comment: If you see in code the statement i.e. `Author eAuthor = (Author)eEvoObject.GetOriginalObject();` where `eEvoObject` is a list, its mean each time there'll be a new `Author` in object `eAuthor`

Comment: @Taufel: No, for my employer

Answer (score 1):

Using linq to get the highest as you mentioned in your comments:

```
int? highestCat = tPapers.Values.GroupBy(p => p.Item1)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                .FirstOrDefault()?.Key;

Console.WriteLine($"Highest Paper_Category is: { highestCat }");
```

Comment: Will I get the key or `Paper_Category` in `highestCat` ?

Comment: @Taufel Yes, it is `Item1` in the values of the dictionary.

Comment: If the `eAuthor` is a list and I have to check highest `Paper_Category` count among all `eAuthor`s, then?

Comment: @Taufel `eAuthor` is a list of what type ? We need to see the class then. Please provide a complete example in your question to make it clear.